# Como recuperar nome do usuário logado e apresentar na View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, asp.net-identity

Estou tentando desenvolver uma pagina, onde apôs o login do usuário, ele é redirecionado para uma index, onde gostaria de exibir o nome do usuário.

Estou utilizando `Identity` default do `ASP.NET MVC`.

Então pensei em colocar na `view` o seguinte código:

```
                <!-- menu profile quick info -->
                <div class="profile">
                    <div class="profile_pic">
                        <img src="~/images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile_info">
                        <span>Seja Bem vindo,</span>
                        <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Identity.Name)</h2>
                        @*<h2>John Doe</h2>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Porém estou com dificuldades para utilizar o tal do `Razor`.

- Está correto utilizar `@Html.LabelFor`?

No começo da pagina, defini:

```
@model OneeWeb.Models.ApplicationUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

- Este é o model responsável por ter os dados do usuário?

Comment: Caso queira mostrar um valor diferente do `Identity.Name`, avise que estendo a resposta.

Comment: Não a ideia é realmente o Name, mas nao entendi pq posso utilizar direto `@User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa definir esse model na View (não para isso).

Para acessar o **UserName** do usuário, basta colocar o código direto na View, desta forma:

```
<h2>@User.Identity.Name</h2>
```

O fato de poder utilizar direto é que o Identity, é que isso é [uma propriedade da interface IIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.principal.iidentity(v=vs.110).aspx).

A questão de não ter que utilizar o `@Html.LabelFor` é que ele não é algo obrigatório no Razor. Tanto que você pode acessar qualquer propriedade do Model utilizando `@Model.NomeDaPropriedade`, por exemplo:

```
@model OneeWeb.Models.Produto
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


 <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titulo)</h2>
 //ou
 <h2>@Model.Titulo</h2>
```

O [Html.LabelFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D%29) nada mais é do que uma "boa prática".

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou, mas agora eu me perdi, pode me explicar pq neste caso utilizo direto `@User.Identity.Name`

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel Veja se melhora agora